# <object> height ignores parent div height

Tags: html, flash, opera

I have a problem with an flash object. The object is an expanding topbanner, but when retracted, the on mouse over effect still appears on the invisible part of the banner. The code is the following:

```
<div id="exp_banner" style="width:930px; height:180px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 100;">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="test.swf" width="930" height="360">
<param name="movie" value="test.swf">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
</div>
```

I have tried to add a style height to the object with an height of 180px, but then the banner scales down.

Answer (score 1):

make position:relative for parent DIV to make overflow work
and keep wmode="transparent" also to overflow work good for flash object